# angular: add element to a list and select it graphically

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pretty new in angular:
I tried to make a list of elements and when they're selected details are showed.
There is also the possibility to add an element and I'd like to select it by default when this new element is created and inserted in the new list.

Here's my code:

```
  <td style='vertical-align: top;padding-left: 20px;'>
      <div id="heroes">
      <h2 id="myHeroes">Network Map</h2>
          <ul class="heroes">
              <li (click)="onSelectNewNetworkMap()" [class.active]>
                  <span class='icon'> <mat-icon [inline]="true" >add</mat-icon></span>   ADD 
              </li>
              <li *ngFor="let hero of data"
                  (click)="onSelect(hero)"
                  [class.active]="hero === selectedHero">
                  <span class= "{{getFlag(hero.MarketNameHidden)}}"> </span> {{hero.CounterpartyCode}}
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </td>
```

css:

```
li {
    margin: .5em;
    padding: .8em;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    border-radius: .25em;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

li:hover, li.active {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

ts:

```
public constructor(private service: MessagesService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.subscription = this.service.map.subscribe((value) => {
        this.data = value.sort((a, b) => a.MarketName.localeCompare(b.MarketName));
    });
}
```

So, when new data is added, subscriber updates the new list and I'd like that my new node will be automatically selected.
Thanks so much, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should try async pipe,It might be helpful for you in *ngFor Loop,better to learn it from scratch

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Thanks!